# Delegating to a thread pool using a Selector and SelectionKeys

Tags: java, multithreading

I am writing an application in which the main thread handles many connections through the use of a `Selector` and `SelectionKeys`. I have run into some trouble with a race condition when attempting to pass tasks off to the worker threads.

My main loop looks like this:

```
    selector = Selector.open(); //Create selector

    serverSocketChannel = ServerSocketChannel.open(); //Create socket channel, configure blocking, and bind
    serverSocketChannel.configureBlocking(false);
    serverSocketChannel.bind(new InetSocketAddress(PORT));

    serverSocketChannel.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT); //Register channel to selector

    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(8000);

    while(true){
        selector.select();

        Iterator<SelectionKey> iterator = selector.selectedKeys().iterator();

        while(iterator.hasNext()){
            SelectionKey key = iterator.next();

            if(key.isAcceptable()){
                SocketChannel socketChannel = serverSocketChannel.accept();
                socketChannel.configureBlocking(false);
                socketChannel.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_READ);
            }
            if(key.isReadable()){
                taskList.add(new ReadTask(key));
            }
            if(key.isWritable()){

            }

            iterator.remove();
        }
    }
```

The idea here is that when a client tries to send data to the server, it receives a key with OP_READ interest and then creates a task with that key so that the threadpool can handle the read so as not to block the main thread.

The problem is that calling this loop continues during the process of the key being passed to a worker thread, and the entire time between when `taskList.add(new ReadTask(key));` is called and the eventual `key.channel().read(buffer)` is called, the main thread is still iterating and sees the key as still being selected. After read is called on the key's channel, the key is marked as inactive and doesn't seem to be selected by the selector until another legitimate write from one of the clients prompts the key to be activated again.

Is there a way for me to mark the key so as not to have it added back to the list of selected keys by the selector without calling read? I've tried `selector.selectedKeys.remove(key)`, but this yields a ConcurrentModification Exception.

Answer (score 0):

You should either do the read in the select loop and then start the worker to process the data and prepare the response, or else remove OP_READ from the `interestOps` of the selection key until the response has been sent.

Comment: The worker threads are already started, these tasks are being passed in via a synchronized queue. What you're recommending is that I change OP_READ to a different OP (such as OP_WRITE?) until the read has occurred?